# How can I create Custom Industry Accelerator on Common Data Service?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I want to create a retail solution for Dynamics 365 sales.
Common Data Service has some industry accelerators such as banking, automotive etc. I was wondering can I create my own accelerator? If It is possible how can I do that?

[Please check out the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q1mG.png)
Microsoft tells ISVs can extend the accelerator.But I couldn't find my sample or document how?

Comment: This is a non developer question, and would be much more likely to find an answer on the Microsoft Forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically speaking, Industry Solution Accelerators are nothing but a set of same components that you create/add in the solution using the supported way. In other words, Industry Solution Accelerators is just a term used to denote those foundational components  that Microsoft releases to help accelerate specific industry. You install those solutions as a base solution and then customize the components further to suit your specific business needs.

> Industry solution accelerators are foundational components within the
>   Microsoft Power Platform and Dynamics 365 that enable ISVs and other
>   solution providers to quickly build industry vertical solutions. The
>   accelerators extend the Common Data Model to include new entities to
>   support a data schema for concepts within specific industries.
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/common-data-model/industry-accelerators

..

> Accelerators are industry focused base components that enable ISVs,
>   and other solution providers a way to build solutions that are based
>   on industry standards supported by Microsoft.
>   https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/dynamics365isvsuccess/posts/dynamics-365-brings-industry-focus-through-the-microsoft-power-platform-and-solution-accelerators

So to create your custom Industry Accelerator you need to do something like that:

- Just create a solution and within that solution customize your instance according to your industry needs
- Release the managed but customizable version of your solution as an Accelerator for your specific industry
- Distribute the Accelerator Solution to other businesses in your industry who could install that solution as a base solution and start customizing it to fit their specific business needs

Comment: Thanks, Ali. It's really informative and includes lots of basic information